# Magento 2 Marketplace Extension Submission Issue

Tags: magento2, php, magento2marketplace

I want to submit one of my extension in marketplace.
I submitted and they give me one error while submitting one ajax form.
But I am Following the same steps they gave me to reproduce the error.
But I couldn't able to do that.
In my Extension, there is one simple form and i am submitting that form via ajax on click of submit button but when they are submitting it is not submitted.
Any one faced this kind of issue before then please let me know the solution.

Comment: They must have shared the environment versions they've used while sharing the error. Please try with the same version and I'm sure you would be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: yes, They give me the environment version I tried that also but still, I couldn't able to raise an issue